# How to Convert Byte Array to IplImage using OpenCv?

Tags: c++, opencv, arrays, iplimage

How to Convert Byte Array to IplImage using OpenCv ?

Is it possible to do the conversion here from byte array to IplImage using Opencv ?

Comment: Pixel wise. Create a scan loop and do it manually.

Comment: @BillyL Could you please explain more with sample syntax please ??

Answer (score 0):

Short as

```
uchar mybytes[]={1,255,0,4,1,4,76,43,45};
Mat mymat(3,3,CV_8UC1,mybytes);
```

or analytical

```
int nl= mymat.rows; 
int nc= mymat.cols;
for (int j=0; j<nl; j++) 
{
    uchar* data= mymat.ptr<uchar>(j);
    for (int i=0; i<nc; i++) 
        data[i]= mybytes[j*i];
}
```